# BigCommerce Stencil CLI Blog - Conditions

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there any possible way to display blogs in BC from a certain count? For example, I want my top 3 most recent posts on the top of the blog page, but then beneath in a different format 4 onward would display. Anyway to start with the 4th blog down?

Answer (score 2):

They are returned in most [recent order](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/b3A6MzU5MDUxMjA-get-all-blog-posts), but you can limit the total to 7 in your example.  I would then use Handlebar helpers in your Stencil theme to grab the first 3 for the top section and the next for for the last section.  {{#for 1 3}}{{/for}} for the top section and  {{#for 4 8}}{{/for}} for the bottom section